# Three.js: Change vertex position in vertex shader?

Tags: three.js

In three.js:

I have a problem. I have an object (plane) with a shader material that changes the position of the vertices in the vertex shader. I need to render the plane but is behind the camera and not rendered. How I can do?

Thanks you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just set the frustumCulled property to false on the plane which will make sure it doesn't get frustum culled.

```
plane.frustumCulled = false
```